# Include executable in another executable

Tags: executable

Can I include an .exe file in another, and then run it from the outer program?
For instance, can I make a wget GUI by including it inside my program, or are my only options either using the including the source or supplying the wget binary together with my wrapper?

I am working on Windows and am looking for a solution in c/c++/c#

Comment: in general, yes. But need more details for an exact answer... what OS? what language? what compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

The idea is to 'insert' the exe as a resource to you main application.

[There](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/embed_resources.htm) is a link which explains how to compile resources into delphi exe. Its similar to VC++ or what ever...

Comment: That shows how to embed it as a resource, but it has to be extracted in order to run it. I want to run it directly